# Android speech recognition - how to get access to the audio files?

Tags: applications, samsung-nexus-s, voice-recognition

When doing speech to text using android mobile phone application, I've heard that the files are temporarily stored in `/data/data/com.google.android.voicesearch/files` after the user makes a recording. How I would get read access to those files?

Comment: Probably not without rooting your device, as that's inside an app's private "sandbox" (`/data/data/<package_name>` is almost always "private area", and only accessible by the app itself and root).